# cassandra: search for a record where a field (type set) is null

Tags: cassandra, cql

I need to do this query for cassndra:

`select * from classes where students = null allow filtering;`

students is a set

but looks like set do not allow = operator.

Answer (score 3):

To test this out, I followed the DataStax docs on [Indexing a Collection](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useIndexColl.html).

```
> CREATE TABLE cyclist_career_teams ( id UUID PRIMARY KEY, lastname text, teams set<text> );
> CREATE INDEX team_idx ON cyclist_career_teams ( teams );
```

With the table created and a secondary index on the `teams` set, I then inserted some test data:

```
> SELECT lastname,teams FROM cyclist_career_teams ;

 lastname        | teams
-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             Vos | {'Neiderland bloeit', 'Rabobank Womens Team', 'Rabobonk-Liv Giant', 'Rabobonk-Liv Womens Cycling Team'}
 Van Der Breggen |                   {'Rabobonk-Liv Womens Cycling Team', 'Sengers Ladies Cycling Team', 'Team Flexpoint'}
           Brand |                    {'AA Drink - Leontien.nl', 'Rabobonk-Liv Giant', 'Rabobonk-Liv Womens Cycling Team'}
       Armistead |                                                                                                    null
```

Note that for Lizzie Armistead, I intentionally omitted a value for the `teams` column.  While CQL does not allow the equals "=" relation on set types, it *does* allow `CONTAINS`.  However, attempting to use that with `null` yields a different error:

```
> SELECT lastname,teams FROM cyclist_career_teams WHERE teams CONTAINS null;
[Invalid query] message="Unsupported null value for column teams"
```

The reason for this behavior, is related to how Cassandra has some special treatment for null values and the "null" keyword.  Essentially, writing a null creates a tombstone, which is Cassandra's structure signifying a delete.

Even if Cassandra's treatment of null was not a factor, **you'd still be faced with the problem that a value of "null" is not unique and your query would have to poll each node in the cluster**.  Such use cases are well-known anti-patterns.  Unfortunately, Cassandra is just not good at querying data (or filtering on a key value) which does not exist.

One thing you *could* try, would be to use a string literal to indicate an empty value, like this:

```
> INSERT INTO cyclist_career_teams (id,lastname) VALUES (uuid(),'Armistead',{'empty'});
> SELECT lastname,teams FROM cyclist_career_teams WHERE teams CONTAINS 'empty';

 lastname  | teams
-----------+-----------
 Armistead | {'empty'}

(1 rows)
```

To be honest though, because of the afore-mentioned anti-pattern, **I can't recommend this approach in good faith**.  But with some added application logic at creation time, an "empty" string literal could work for you.